# Calling a specific function seems to prevent `main` from ever executing

Tags: c, llvm

Currently, I'm trying to write a little compiler with LLVM in C, and I cannot seem to get it to run correctly.

This program does not print anything, despite flushing the standard output buffer BEFORE anything else is ran:

```c
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <llvm-c/Transforms/PassManagerBuilder.h>
#include <llvm-c/Analysis.h>
#include <llvm-c/TargetMachine.h>
#include <llvm-c/BitWriter.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("TEST");
    fflush(stdout);

    LLVMContextRef context = LLVMContextCreate();
    LLVMModuleRef module = LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext("test", context);

    LLVMTypeRef f32 = LLVMFloatTypeInContext(context);
    LLVMTypeRef ftype = LLVMFunctionType(f32, 0, 0, 0);
    LLVMValueRef ftest = LLVMAddFunction(module, "ftest", ftype);
    LLVMBasicBlockRef bb = LLVMAppendBasicBlockInContext(context, ftest, "ftest");
    LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVMCreateBuilderInContext(context);
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, bb);
    LLVMValueRef v1 = LLVMConstReal(f32, 2.5);
    LLVMValueRef v2 = LLVMConstReal(f32, 4.3);
    LLVMValueRef result = LLVMBuildFAdd(builder, v1, v2, "f-add");
    LLVMBuildRet(builder, result);
    LLVMVerifyFunction(ftest, LLVMPrintMessageAction);

    char *errors = 0;
    LLVMPrintModuleToFile(module, "module.txt", &errors);
    printf("error: %s\n", errors);

    LLVMDisposeMessage(errors);

    LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos();
    LLVMInitializeAllTargets();
    LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs();
    LLVMInitializeAllAsmParsers();
    LLVMInitializeAllAsmPrinters();

    LLVMTargetRef target;
    LLVMGetTargetFromTriple(LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple(), &target, &errors);
    printf("error: %s\n", errors);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(errors);
    printf("target: %s, [%s], %d, %d\n", LLVMGetTargetName(target), LLVMGetTargetDescription(target), LLVMTargetHasJIT(target), LLVMTargetHasTargetMachine(target));
    printf("triple: %s\n", LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple());
    printf("features: %s\n", LLVMGetHostCPUFeatures());
    LLVMTargetMachineRef machine = LLVMCreateTargetMachine(target, LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple(), "generic", LLVMGetHostCPUFeatures(), LLVMCodeGenLevelDefault, LLVMRelocDefault, LLVMCodeModelDefault);

    LLVMSetTarget(module, LLVMGetDefaultTargetTriple());
    LLVMTargetDataRef datalayout = LLVMCreateTargetDataLayout(machine);
    char *datalayout_str = LLVMCopyStringRepOfTargetData(datalayout);
    printf("datalayout: %s\n", datalayout_str);
    LLVMSetDataLayout(module, datalayout_str);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(datalayout_str);

    LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(machine, module, "result.o", LLVMObjectFile, &errors);
    printf("error: %s\n", errors);
    LLVMDisposeMessage(errors);
    return 0;
}
```

The program still compiles and runs, but nothing is ever printed to the console.

Yet when I comment out following lines, it runs as expected:

```c
    // LLVMInitializeAllTargetInfos();
    // LLVMInitializeAllTargets();
    // LLVMInitializeAllTargetMCs();
    // LLVMInitializeAllAsmParsers();
    // LLVMInitializeAllAsmPrinters();
```

I'm running Windows with MinGW and using `LLVM v15.0.6`, building with the following command:

```
gcc -I(LLVM Path)/include test.c (LLVM Path)/bin/LLVM-C.dll
```

Comment: "The program still compiles and runs, but nothing is ever printed to the console." Add `fflush(stdout);` between `printf("This should print");` and `LLVMInitializeAllTargets();` and report outcome.  I suspect `LLVMInitializeAllTargets();` in not completing for some reason.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That worked, but with a bigger example it does not

Comment: I edited it with the example that does not work

Comment: Possibly, either your includes redefine printf or fflush, or the libraries you link with also drag in a modified version of printf/fflush. Another possibility is that using this library drags in an alternate version  of the startup (I mean, the code which calls main()) or maybe there is a callback mechanism in the startup which is used by LLVM to tweak the way printf works.

Comment: I suggest you replace " printf("TEST");" with "write(1,"TEST\n",5);" to bypass the C library as a first debug step

Comment: Not sure if this helps but hopefully provides some useable info; I am able to compile and run this on ubuntu using gcc and the llvm-dev package, getting the following output: `TESTerror: (null)
error: (null)
target: x86-64, [64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64], 1, 1
...
datalayout: e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128
error: (null)` Have you tried using a debugger to follow execution and see where it gets stuck/what printf is calling under the hood that it doesnt seem to work?